# Python and .exe files, another way

Tags: python, py2exe

How to build exe files from py files (compatible with win32)?

please don't refer to py2exe. that is blocked service in IRI.

- for Iranians only: do you know how to download something (like py2exe) from blocked sites? especially from sourceforge ande fontforge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (link to preliminary [python 2.6 on Windows](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Python26Win) bin)?

Answer (score 4):

Pick up a mirror like this

http://git.kitsu.ru/mirrors/py2exe.git

and download it with git clone, and compile it by running setup.py after that.

Comment: I agree... I still dont understand how py2exe can be a "blocked service". If an url is blocked: pick a mirror. Once you have it locally, how can the program be blocked?

Comment: @mizipzor: py2exe is not blocked service,

all happens is this: one day sourceforge decide Iranian people must not be able to use me ...

Answer (score 1):

Legal issues aside, blocked sites can be accessed (and downloaded from) using any external web proxy.

**Edit**: Does this work for you? [Sourceforge.net through hidemyass.com](http://1.2.hidemyass.com/index.php?q=aHR0cDovL3NvdXJjZWZvcmdlLm5ldA%3D%3D&hl=0).

Comment: @mizipzor: could you explain more? i don't know anything about servers and network issues.

Comment: @mizipzor: no! this domain is filtered (blocked by government).

Comment: hidemyass.com? then just find another web proxy... find a list of free ones and start going through them, some are bound to be open. I still think that youre tackling the wrong problem here though. Py2exe cant be blocked, its a program you run locally. If you find it on a (nonblocked) mirror, you should be fine.

Comment: Just saw your comment on S.Mark's answer. If its just sourceforge that blocks you, his answer should work: get py2exe from some other place, not sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

How about cx_Freeze, is that blocked?

Refer to: http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Pydroid: my dear friend, sourceforge blocks all of its services for Iranian people.